# What is the finite eigenvalue of a controlled system as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$?

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, systems-theory

Consider a state space system (A, B) as follows:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
    a_1 & a_2 \\
    -a_2 & 0 \\
    \end{bmatrix},
B= \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
    1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$$

where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are real constants and $a_1 \ne 0$. Furthermore, let

$$Q=\begin{bmatrix}
    0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 \\
    \end{bmatrix},
R = \epsilon^2$$

where $\epsilon > 0$. Let $P(\epsilon)$ be the positive definite solution, assuming it exists, of the algebraic Riccati equation:

$$A^TP + PA - PBR^{-1}B^TP + Q = 0.$$

What is the finite eigenvlue(s) of $A- \epsilon^{-2}BB^TP(\epsilon)$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$?

I have figured out that if a positive definite solution $P(\epsilon)$ exists, then $a_2 \ne 0$. However, I am unable to calculate $P(\epsilon)$. Is there a trick to find the eigenvalues of $A- \epsilon^{-2}BB^TP(\epsilon)$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are dealing with LQR and they ask about the closedloop eigenvalues, the first thing that comes to mind is to use the associated [Hamiltonian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_Riccati_equation#Solution)

$$
H = 
\begin{bmatrix}
A & -\epsilon^{-2} B\,B^\top \\ -Q & -A^\top
\end{bmatrix},
$$

which should have negated eigenvalue pairs and the two negative eigenvalues should match the closedloop eigenvalues. Solving directly for the eigenvalues of $H$ as a function of $a_1$, $a_2$ and $\epsilon$ would require solving a [quartic equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_equation). However, it is easier to make use of the stated property of $H$, namely from that it follows that its [characteristic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial) would be of the form

$$
\det(\lambda\,I - H) = (\lambda - p_1)\,(\lambda + p_1)\,(\lambda - p_2)\,(\lambda + p_2) = p_1^2\,p_2^2 - (p_1^2 + p_2^2)\,\lambda^2 + \lambda^4.
$$

Matching the actual characteristic polynomial with this form allows one to find expressions for $p_1^2$ and $p_2^2$ relatively easily. Now, when one applies the limit of $\epsilon \to 0$ to these solutions one will remain bounded while the other does not.

Comment: I am not sure if this would be the easiest way to obtain the answer. So maybe there are other tricks to obtain this result faster. For example the fact that one eigenvalue becomes unbounded and the other doesn't reminds me of the rootlocus with for a transfer function with less zeros than poles.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. How do you know that one of the eigenvalues will remain bounded and the other will not without solving for the eigenvalues?

Comment: @daliu I did solve for the eigenvalues and solved the limit, but since this looks like homework I didn't wanted to give you the answer directly. Hopefully, this does point you sufficiently in the right direction. If not, feel free to ask for clarifications.

Comment: If I am correct, the characteristic polynomial of the Hamiltonian matrix is $\lambda^{4} − (a_1+\epsilon^{-2}) \lambda^{2} − a_2^4 − \epsilon^{-2}=0$. I do not know how to turn this into the form you provided. WolframAlpha says that both of the solutions are unbounded. How did you obtain the eigenvalues?

Comment: @daliu Your expression for the characteristic polynomial looks incorrect. To be honest when I worked this problem out I did not feel like calculating and simplifying the determinant of a four by four matrix and just used Matlab instead (this also help avoiding making mistakes in my calculations).

Comment: The expression I got for the characteristic polynomial is $\lambda^4 + (2\,a_2^2-a_1^2-\epsilon^{-2}) \lambda^{2} + a_2^4 + a_1^2\,\epsilon^{-2}$.

Comment: @daliu You could also write the characteristic polynomial as $\left(\lambda^4 + (2\,a_2^2 - a_1^2)\,\lambda^2 + a_2^4\right) \epsilon^2 + a_1^2 - \lambda^2 = 0$, from which it is easier to extract the the two finite eigenvalues more directly.

Comment: I did not know that you can multiply by a limit when when a term tends towards infinity. In that case, the question is solved.

However, the characteristic polynomial I calculated is still $\lambda^2 (\lambda^2 - a_1^2) - a_2^4 - \epsilon^{-2} ( \lambda^2 - a_1^2) = 0$, or $ \epsilon^2 \lambda^2 (\lambda^2 - a_1^2) - ( \lambda^2 - a_1^2)$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$. The finite eigenvalue of the closed-loop system is then $-\abs{a_1}$.

Comment: @daliu there are probably some mathematical exceptions when you can't multiply by the limit, but I think in this case I think it would be allowed. Also tried to verify it with numerical calculations and used smaller and smaller values for $\epsilon$ and it seemed to match, so I am sufficiently confident that this approach yields the correct solution.